# Downside to using two WCF services instead of one with callback?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a client/server setup that I am implementing using a WCF Service (`NetTcpBinding`). The setup is such that the client basically sends a few commands and instructions to the server (mostly one-way calls). The server, however, may be in a situation where it needs to send a lot of data back to the client very rapidly. I've got this implemented currently using callbacks on the main WCF service (the server makes these callbacks very frequently).

But I'm having a heck of a time getting it to work correctly. It mostly seems to come down to exceptions/hangs (mostly hangs) that are occurring when the client calls to the server while the server is in the process of sending lots of data back to the client. I've tried just about everything have seen such as setting up most of my calls as `[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]` and setting `ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` on the `ServiceBehavior`. This has reduced the number of hangs, but not stopped them.

So, since it is most important for me to get a working solution quickly (deadlines approaching), I'm considering refactoring to have two WCF services. The first would be just like all the client-server calls now with the commands. The second would be in the opposite direction and would be setup after the client connected to the server. This service would be used to send the data back to the client.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach? Any problems with having WCF services going in both directions? Any other tips or tricks? Or am I completely off-base for this?

Comment: Is it possible to break up your response into several pages that the client would then make subsequent requests to retrieve? I don't know if sending a lot of data through a single service call is a good idea.

Comment: @Kekoa - Not really... That wouldn't really fit the requirements. The point of the service is to monitor a data-feed in something approximating real-time. I could "chunk" the data somewhat... or I guess I could just have the client request the data at some interval ("GetLastData" kind of call). Hrm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a bad idea to me.  The first service can add the commands or whatever to a queue that the second service uses to process in order.

You could even have the second service call back to the first service which would then call back to the clients.  That way the clients just talk with one service which really doesn't do much other than take requests and spit back results.  The second service could do its thing in its own time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tricky situation, I don't think it is terrible to do it the way you have outlined, though there may be some maintenance drawbacks.

The server would need to know the address of the clients to call their WCF service.  This may not be a problem at first, but then if you add clients or upgrade clients, you might have some challenges there.

If clients are responsible for making all the calls, then that makes it easier to maintain when you scale out.

Going off of your comment above, if what you are after is near-real-time monitoring, I question the use of WCF at all for that. It may take more time to set up(as in not for this deadline), but you might have better luck with systems tailored for that in the long run.

I would probably go with a multicast queuing solution, where you have one server, but multiple listeners, then your server keeps pushing items(possibly lines of text) in the queue and clients read it.  Something like AMQP(like rabbitmq), MSMQ(haven't used it but it's by Microsoft), zeromq, etc.

Or even simple socket communication would give you more performance, and you won't have a framework timing you out(look at zeromq, it works almost like a socket). This way clients can connect, and receive updates and disconnect when they don't want anymore.